# What should you call a property, like an invariant, but that is reversed instead of preserved?

Tags: terminology, invariance

Suppose $P$ is some property of some objects and $f$ is a function on those objects. If $Px$ implies $Pf(x)$ and $\lnot Px$ implies $\lnot Pf(x)$, then we might say that "$P$ is invariant under $f$".

Suppose that instead, $P$ is a property such that $Px$ implies $\lnot P f(x)$ and $\lnot Px$ implies $Pf(x)$. What is the correct terminology for this situation?

Comment: Is there a particular context where you've encountered this property of a property?

Comment: @EthanBolker $P$ is a property of positions $x$ in a game. For a certain transformation (isomorphism) $f$ on game positions, $f$ reverses property $P$.

Comment: Tempted to suggest "flippant", I instead suggest "anti-invariant" or "reversed", if there isn't a standard term already.

Comment: you might say "P has odd parity under $f$"

Comment: I am all for flippant!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term **anti-invariant** seems to be in use for what I believe is this general idea.
The [Wikipedia glossary of invariant theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_invariant_theory) defines an anti-invariant as

> A relative invariant transforming according to a character of order 2 of a group such as the symmetric group.

which, if my understanding of the relevant terms is correct, is a special case of what I want.
Also,
an "anti-invariant Riemannian submersion" involves a function not mapping a set to itself, but instead mapping a set to its orthogonal complement (defined e.g. [here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1302.5108v1.pdf)).
Other uses of the term "anti-invariant" can be found by google, e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1373569/weyl-anti-invariant-differential-operators-on-spheres) and [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=9q6_O6AwAhQC&pg=PA161&lpg=PA161&dq=anti-invariant+property&source=bl&ots=cX6pxqykYq&sig=YK1JcJthjFJtBC_3Ayc_ReX4kOY&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CEwQ6AEwB2oVChMI0ePD3Z6DxwIVU52ICh03tA37#v=onepage&q=anti-invariant%20property&f=false), though it's hard to jump in without context and figure out what the term means.

In conclusion, I think that if one were in great need of a concise term to use repeatedly, anti-invariant would be a good choice. But for most purposes it is probably best to write out "$Px \implies \lnot P f(x)$" explicitly, or in words.